# Delphi 10.2 TWebBrowser : where is Document property?

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser

I'm trying to create an Android (multi-device) application with Delphi 10.2 that uses `TWebBrowser`. I load a URL and I want to parse its contents for fields, but I don't know how do it.

I read this excellent guide: http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/delphi/twebbrowser/twebbrowser_oleobject.htm#OleObject.Document, but the property `WebBrowser.OleObject.Document` doesn't exist.

Can somebody help me, please?

Answer (score 2):

The TWebBrowser for FMX is completely different from TWebBrowser for VCL.  The VCL one makes use (for access to the Document, etc) of interfaces provided by Internet Explorer, or rather the DLLs on which it is based.  IE only runs on Windows, so you shouldn't be surprised to learn that the interfaces it provides are not available on FMX.

The FMX TWebBrowser is a completely different and far more limited beast.  It is not automatable in the same way TWebBrowser for VCL/Windows is, and some would say that is a good thing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you know some links where i can find how to read the HTML content of a displayed page, at least, please ?

Comment: I suggest you post that as a new q.

Comment: @JimPapas: The documentation for [FMX.TWebBrowser](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/FMX.WebBrowser.TWebBrowser) would be a place to start.